# Passing function to class in Python

Tags: python, function, class, python-3.x, menu

So I'm working on a class structure for a text-based menu. I need to create the menus and set the actions before actually running the code. So to avoid the function being called to early, I have created a class called Run which takes the given function and runs it. My problem is that I don't know how I should handle the arguments for the function. What I have so far, and which doesn't work is:

```
class Run:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def execute(self):
        print('Running')
        self.func

def foo(*args):
    print(*args)

baz = Run(foo('bar'))

baz.execute()
```

Just to be clear I first want the function to run when I run `baz.execute()`

Comment: Why don't you just use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)? Your current attempt is calling `foo` then passing the result to `Run.__init__`, so is doomed to failure.

Comment: I don't know `functools.partial` could you elaborate?

Comment: ...so why don't you read about it via the link I provided?

Comment: I'm pretty new to python, and the documentation, whilst precise, isn't always the most newcomer friendly :(

Comment: But, having read it as best you can, you should at least be able to ask a more specific question than *"could you elaborate"* or, heaven forfend, go and *try something*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the function before you pass it to `Run`, so `func` is actually the result of calling it (`None`, as it doesn't return anything). The minimal fix is:

```
class Run:

    def __init__(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        self.func = func
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def execute(self):
        print('Running')
        self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)  # call func here


baz = Run(foo, 'bar')  # don't call func here
baz.execute()
```

However, you can just use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to do this, removing the need to maintain your own class and tack `.execute` onto the eventual call (which you could also eliminate by renaming `execute` to [`__call__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__):

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> def foo(*args):
    print(*args)


>>> baz = partial(foo, 'bar')
>>> baz
functools.partial(<function foo at 0x1059c4400>, 'bar')
>>> baz()
bar
```